# How to describe a person who has two functions in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, american-english, word-order

What would be the shortest way to say someone has two jobs or obligations in a sentence? I am searching for a universal way to use this. I can say “an abandoned daughter, a lonesome father, or a fearful sister” but how can I do the same with someone who is a mother and a politician, father, and a doctor, or a sister and a cop?
If I write:
"A mother and a doctor searches for her way out..."
Word and other apps automatically correct “searches” into “search,” because they think these are two different persons.

Answer (score 3):

You could set the phrase as an appositive.  "Joan, a mother and a doctor, searches for her way out."

Comment: That is an excellent idea. Unfortunately, I cannot use names in the sentence. It is for a logline and names are a big no-no in them.

Comment: What about, "The woman, a mother and doctor, searches for her way out?" or "A mother, who's also a doctor, searches for her way out?"

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I was hoping there was a shorter way to solve this, but as it seems, there is none. I have gone through 1000+ loglines and found nothing in the matter of what I have been searching for.